# Wordpress - Separate Log in and Register forms in the same page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication, registration

I need to create a page in Wordpress. In it I need to have three tabs: Log In, Register, Forgot Password. Obviously, they will contain a login form, a registration form and a password recovery form. I have found instructions on how to create custom login form here:

http://www.tutorialstag.com/custom-wordpress-login-without-using-a-plugin.html

and how to create a custom registration form here:

http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html

Those two solutions seem good to me, so I'd like to use them. The problem occurs because both codes use $_POST for sending data and they both execute certain code in if($_POST) loops. Now, if I put both codes on the same page, and if a user tries to log in, it will also trigger the registration form's if($_POST) loop, and vice versa.

Is there a way for me to separate these two loops, something like if($_POST['login']) and if($_POST['register']) or in some other way?

Ideally, I want to create a plugin which adds shortcodes for login form, registration form and forgot password form. What is the best way to separate codes and yet make them work together in the same page?

Also, is there perhaps an easier way to achieve what I need? I've tried looking for plugins that might look alike, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and pretty much as you've described here.

Set the 'name' attribute on each of your submit buttons - e.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="mybtnclass" />
```

Then when parsing, check if that value is set

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) :
  // Do login
elseif(isset($_POST['register'])) :
  // Do registration
elseif(isset($_POST['reset'])) :
  // Do password reset
endif;
```

EDIT:

An alternative is to give all the buttons the same 'name' and then test the 'value' attribute to determine which was pressed e.g.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="mybtnclass" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="mybtnclass" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset Password" class="mybtnclass" />

<?php
if('Login'===$_POST['submit']) : 
  // Do login
elseif('Register'===$_POST['submit']) : 
  // Do register
elseif('Reset Password'===$_POST['submit']) : 
  // Do password reset
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Mark you're a legend. This worked like a charm. Thank you so much.